# chrome.declarativeNetRequest does not work for action types requiring host permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm migrating my app to manifest v3 so I need to replace `webRequest` with `declarativeNetRequest`.

The problem is that those action types such as `webRequest` and `redirect` that require host permissions don't work even if I add `https://*/*` to the `permissions` array in the manifest.

For example, the following rule doesn't work at all when I visit stackoverflow. Actually, `chrome.declarativeNetRequest.onRuleMatchedDebug.addListener` never detects the relevant requests.

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "modifyHeaders",
            "responseHeaders": [
                { "header": "cookie", "operation": "remove" },
                { "header": "h2", "operation": "set", "value": "v2" },
                { "header": "h3", "operation": "append", "value": "v3" }
            ]
        },
        "condition": {
            "initiatorDomains": [
                "stackoverflow.com"
            ]
        }
    }
```

But if I change the action to `block` (i.e. an action that does not demand host permissions),

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": {
            "type": "block"
        },
        "condition": {
            "initiatorDomains": [
                "stackoverflow.com"
            ]
        }
    }
```

it works instantly.

Could you anybody help me out to have the `redirect` and `modifyHeaders`  actions work?

Comment: In MV3 it's `host_permissions`, not `permissions`.